# Can't Preview Excel in Office Web Apps but available to view in browser

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, excel, office-web-apps

I recently deployed Office Web Apps for SharePoint 2013, the preview of Excel docs returns

> We can't show a preview of this item.

It will display in a browser if that option is selected. This is a simple excel file. All my research has not found an answer. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: I'm unsure, but did you make a full crawl/index reset after implementing OWA? And i think if it is a older file format or macro enabled, OWA will be unable to preview the file. Try to copy the content and save as the last file format (.xlsx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but we did run a crawl and the documents are simple file and the latest format.

Answer (score 0):

Upon reviewing the WFE ULS logs, I discovered an error about not being able to connect to the FQDN of the OWA server. I tried to ping the OWA server from the WFE and was not successful. I added an entry into the WFE local hosts file for the FQDN of the OWA server. The error previewing excel files stopped.